# AssociationType 'Committee_Member_Contact' has a referential integrity constraint and cannot be mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting AssociationType 'Committee_Member_Contact' has a referential integrity constraint and cannot be mapped in EDMX file. In my database there is not relationship between like PK and FK. `Committee_Member` table can have multiple `Contact's. I have created`Referential Constraint`as 'Contact` is Primary and `Committee_Member` as Dependent.

```
public partial class Committee_Member
{
    public byte[] Committee_Member_Id { get; set; }          
    public byte[] Contact_Id { get; set; }           
    public string Committee_Code { get; set; }
    public string External_Source_Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> External_Last_Update { get; set; }         

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
public partial class Contact
{
   public Contact()
   {
        this.Committee_Member_SPE = new HashSet<Committee_Member_SPE>();
   }
   public byte[] Contact_Id { get; set; }
   public string First_Name { get; set; }
   public string Last_Name { get; set; }
   ....
   public virtual ICollection<Committee_Member_SPE> Committee_Member_SPE { get; set; }
}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Potentially related question:  Why are your keys byte arrays?

Comment: It's CRM Db.. That product creates like that